# Исключение при выводе строки, выходящей за пределы окна (Python, curses)

Tags: python, строки, curses

С помощью модуля `curses.panel` происходит вывод диалогового окна. У `subwin` этой панели есть область куда выводится текстовое сообщение из внешней переменной. Если текстовое сообщение не содержит новых строк и превышает размер текстовой области - то всё проходит без проблем (так как текст добавляется через `addnstr`, ограничивающую длину всего текста, в соответствии с размерами окна панели). Но если переменная с сообщением содержит новые строки ('`\n`') - то в случае когда сообщение не влазит в размеры области текста - происходит ошибка.

Вот сама функция:

```
def Panel(screen, h, w, y, x, text):
    new_window = curses.newwin(h, w, y, x)
    new_window.erase()
    new_window.box()
    sub_window = new_window.subwin(h - 2, w - 2 , y + 1 , x + 1)
    sub_window.addnstr(0, 0, text, ((h - 2) * (w - 2) - 1))
    panel = curses.panel.new_panel(new_window)
    curses.panel.update_panels()
    screen.refresh()
    screen.getch()
```

Передаваемые в функцию переменные `h` и `w` (высота и ширина окна) - задаются динамически. То есть ошибка возникает почти всегда, в случае если есть новая строка и окно терминала маленького размера.

Как проще всего решить эту проблему?

Понимаю, что можно написать отдельную функцию заменяющую '`\n`' на пробелы, в зависимости от ширины окна, но может есть какое-то штатное решение или что-нибудь попроще и поэлегантнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что использование метода `insstr` вместо `addnstr` решает проблему, вставленная через `insstr` строка, какого бы размера она не была - не вызывает исключения:

```
def Panel(screen, h, w, y, x, text):
    new_window = curses.newwin(h, w, y, x)
    new_window.erase()
    new_window.box()
    sub_window = new_window.subwin(h - 2, w - 2 , y + 1 , x + 1)
    sub_window.insstr(0, 0, text)
    panel = curses.panel.new_panel(new_window)
    curses.panel.update_panels()
    screen.refresh()
    screen.getch()
```